# Windows 7 Power Button Turn off Display

Tags: windows-7, display, power-management

In the define power Buttons and turn on password protection page in the Windows 7 Control panel, the user has the option to have the power button do the following:

- Nothing
- Sleep
- Hibernate
- Shutdown

Is it possible to have the power button turn off the display but not sleep the computer?

The end goal of this is to have a WMC remote turn off the display for a computer, but not sleep it.

Answer (score 1):

not within the normal windows user settings.

I use a laptop sometimes connected to my TV, I find the "close lid or screen" behaviour is the way to go. Mine is set to "do nothing" when i close the laptop screen. This means the playback on the laptop continues via hdmi or plex but I don't have a duplicate screen distracting me.

Hope you agree with my solution.

William

Answer (score 1):

The only given option is to have the display enter sleep mode,set in power options,with time delay that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only options are on Windows 7:

- Do nothing
- Sleep
- Hibernate
- Shut down

You can't just turn the monitor off by pressing the power button.  But if you don't want to power off completely but reserve some energy, you can put it into **sleep** instead.  (Sleep is also known as "standby" in Windows XP.)